# Clamp the value of a BehaviorSubject

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactivex, rx.net

Is it possible to *transform*/*validate* the value of a `ISubject<T>` ?

E.g. I have a `BehaviorSubject<double> zoomFactor = new(1);` that I would like to be clamped between `0.1` and `10`.

- It should be possible to call `zoomFactor.OnNext(Math.Clamp(newZoomFactor, 0.1, 10))`, but doing so puts the responsibility on the caller, which I wish to avoid.
- I could transform upon observation using `zoomFactor.Select(newZoomFactor => Math.Clamp(newZoomFactor, 0.1, 10))`, but:

  - This is outsourcing responsibility onto another caller again;
  - The original `zoomFactor` value wouldn't be changed here: imagine the user zooming out past the limit, and zooming back in, yet the rendered zoom is stuck to `10` during the time the actual value silently gets back into the clamped bounds internally...

Comment: Yes, you can transform a value of a subject by using `.Select`. That's what it's there for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about creating a custom `ISubject<T>` implementation with the desirable behavior?

```
class BehaviorTransformSubject<T> : ISubject<T>
{
    private readonly BehaviorSubject<T> _subject;
    private readonly Func<T, T> _transform;

    public BehaviorTransformSubject(T value, Func<T, T> transform)
    {
        _subject = new BehaviorSubject<T>(value);
        _transform = transform;
    }

    public void OnNext(T value) => _subject.OnNext(_transform(value));
    public void OnCompleted() => _subject.OnCompleted();
    public void OnError(Exception error) => _subject.OnError(error);
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> o) => _subject.Subscribe(o);
}
```

Usage example:

```
ISubject<double> zoomFactor = new BehaviorTransformSubject<double>(1.0,
    x => Math.Clamp(x, 0.1, 10.0));
```

---

**Alternative implementation:** The `OnNext` method could be implemented alternatively like this:

```
public void OnNext(T value)
{
    T newValue;
    try { newValue = _transform(value); }
    catch (Exception ex) { _subject.OnError(ex); return; }
    _subject.OnNext(newValue);
}
```

This one handles differently a possible failure of the `transform` function. Instead of throwing the error directly back on the producer who invoked the `OnNext` method, it propagates it to the consumers of the subject, causing its irreversible termination (no more values will be propagated through this subject). I guess that the original `OnNext` implementation has the semantics that you are looking for, but I might be wrong.

To be fair the [`Math.Clamp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.clamp) method never fails (according to the docs), so this distinction is mostly academic in your case.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236087/discussion-on-answer-by-theodor-zoulias-clamp-the-value-of-a-behaviorsubject).